# Javascript .click() function completes desired action partially whereas it works perfectly when clicking manually

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have designed a Profile Page and besides each element there is an edit link, which opens a bootstrap popover, inside which there is a textbox and a save button. Inside the Edit link there is no text, instead there is a pencil icon to signify it. When i click on the link a toggle function is called on the onclick event which changes the icon to an X signifying it's the same button to close the popover. What happens behind the scenes is that it checks which is the current image inside the and updates the src attribute with the path to other image.

Then after the user types the new value and clicks on save an ajax call is made to the server which updates the value in the database and returns a JSON response. If the server responds updated successfully, the value of the label where the name is shown and in the navbar, both are updated with the new value, and i use the click() function to close the popover..

If i click on the link without updating the value inside popover, the image toggles back to pencil icon what it should.

Now the issue that comes up is that when i use the javascript .click() function, the popover is closed, but the image is not toggled, it remains the same.

Sorry can't Add Screenshots to ease the understanding as i am new to Stack Overflow and posting images requires 10 reputation..

Adding Code:

Profile View :

```
<div id="Shared_Profile_Outer_Name">
        <span class="lead"><strong id="Shared_Profile_Value_Name">@Profile.Name</strong>  </span>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-html="true"
           data-original-title="" title="" id="Shared_Profile_Toggle_Name"
           data-content='<h5><strong>Name</strong></h5>
            <input type="text" id="Shared_Profile_Input_Name" class="form-control" value="@Profile.Name"><br />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="shared.Profile.UpdateName()">Save</button>'>
            <img src="/Images/edit.png" id="Shared_Profile_Toggle_Image_Name" onclick="shared.Profile.Toggle(this.id)"
                 style="width:20px;height:20px;vertical-align:text-top" />
        </a>
    </div>
```

Javascript Toggle Code:

```
    shared.Profile.Toggle = function (elem) {
    var cur = document.getElementById(elem).getAttribute('src').slice(8, -4);
    if (cur == "edit") { document.getElementById(elem).setAttribute('src', '/Images/cancel.png'); }
    else { document.getElementById(elem).setAttribute('src', '/Images/edit.png'); }
};
```

Javascript AJAX Code:

```
  shared.Profile.UpdateName = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Shared/UpdateName/",    // The URL for the request
        data: { Name: document.getElementById('Shared_Profile_Input_Name').value },
        type: "POST",            // Whether this is a POST or GET request
        dataType: "json",       // The type of data we expect back
        beforeSend: function () {   
            document.getElementById("Progress_Bar").style.display = "block";
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        },  // Code that is run before sending
        success: function (json) {  // Code to run if the request succeeds the response is passed to the function
            if (json == "Name Updation Successful") {
                document.getElementById('Shared_Profile_Value_Name').innerText = document.getElementById('Shared_Profile_Input_Name').value;
            }
            document.getElementById('Shared_Navigation_CurrentLoggedInUser').innerText = document.getElementById('Shared_Profile_Input_Name').value;
            document.getElementById('Shared_Profile_Toggle_Name').click();
            navigation.notify(json, "Success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {    // Code to run if the request fails; the raw request and status codes are passed to the function
            navigation.notify("Sorry, there was a problem!", "Error");
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
            console.log("Status: " + status);
            console.dir(xhr);
        },
        complete: function (xhr, status) { document.getElementById("Progress_Bar").style.display = "none"; },   // Code to run regardless of success or failure
    });
};
```

Any kind of help will be grateful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be triggering the click() function on `Shared_Profile_Toggle_Image_Name` and not `Shared_Profile_Input_Name`. You have bound the `toggle()` function to `Shared_Profile_Toggle_Image_Name`

Comment: Thanks a lot bro.. Saved me a lot of time..as the deadlines were too close.